# Load parameters from file?

Tags: c#

I was wonder if anyone could help me with a problem I am experiencing.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is this: I have an int and a button click;

```
public static Int32 MyInt(String A, String B, Single X, Single Y, Single Z)
{
    return Model(A, B, X, Y, Z);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Model(want to load my parameters from a .txt file)
{
```

Is it possible to load parameters from .txt file? I apologize if this doesn't make sense, I am new to coding.

Edit Further Detail

I have a button which uses 2 textboxes and 3 numericupdowns and edits memory of a process i am attached to meanwhile sending a string representation of that to a listbox in format of Model(A, B, X, Y, Z); everytime I press it.

I then save to .txt file. i.e

Model(hello, bye, 2, 4, 6);
Model(hello, bye, 8, 10, 12);

Now what I want is when I press load it does this for me. If this makes better sense

Comment: How does yout txt file look like?

Comment: Yes you can do this. I would encourage you to use an XML file.

Comment: I can make my text file look 1 of two ways either Model(hello, bye, 2, 6, 8); or without the model

Comment: Tempted for -1: indeed it is possible to load parameters from text file - most of configuration files are plain text (including .ini and .config). Without shown format there is nothing more to say about it.

Comment: Side note: when editing please remove all "new here" and "thank you" - check [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for discussion.

Comment: Im ok with the -1, no big deal. Like I said I am a very inexperienced coder, just looking for abit of help, we all start somewhere. Appreciate your help none the less

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok no problem

Comment: Side note: Are you inventing some format for fun OR there is some external format you need to match? There is really no good reason to try inventing your own format - don't like XML - use JSON, anything that have known working parser... On other hand if you feel need to invent your own - please read something on existing ones first - at least check out CSV and related issues.

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways in which you can consider loading your parameters from a file.

1. Consider loading from [APP.config / Web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. Have a custom XML configuration file
3. Have your on custom text file (in formats like CSV, or just parameters separated by commas)

If you can give some idea about what suits your requirement I (other SO users) will post some code samples.

If your file just need to have the parameters in separate lines in a simple text file as you mentioned see the following sample.

```
    String[] parameters = System.IO.File.FileReadAllLines("parameters.txt");
    string A = parameters[0];
    string B = parameters[1];
    Single X = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[2]);
    Single Y = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[3]);
    Single Z = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[4]);
```

**It is to give you an idea (a lot is missing** like error checking, and better representation of the parameters in the file etc).

I would recommend look into the application in a holistic manner and identify all such parameters and identify a way of organizing them in a config or xml file as needed. But if it is a simple sample app much analysis may not be needed. Still it might make more sense to put it in a config  file over a text file.

Comment: appreciate help but I need it in .txt files. I'll edit my post with more detail

Comment: Yes. please let me know if this works or if you need further assistance. Hope you will be able to move forward with your project. Have fun coding..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your text file contains parameters delimited by newline as below:

Sample File:

```
param1=value1 
param2=value2
param3=value3
```

Try This:

```
using system.IO;

String [] strLines=File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\file1.txt");
String [] strParamNames=new String[strLines.Length];
String [] strParamValues=new String[strLines.Length];

for(int i=0;i<strLines.Length;i++)
{
   strParamNames[i]=strLines[i].Split('=')[0].Trim();
   strParamValues[i]=strLines[i].Split('=')[1].Trim();
}
```

Comment: No it is just one string per line of everytime I pressed button so Model(A, B, X, Y, Z);

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first

1. read file
2. assign to a variable
3. pass variable to method.

   ```
   tring[] params = System.IO.File.FileReadAllLines("parameters.txt");
   string a = params[0];
   string b = params[1];
   ```